# Web method throws internal error..parameters match so not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Very old 1.1 vb.net / asp.net web app.  I'm trying to make an ajax call to fill an autocomplete text box with this:

```
    $("#ucAddActionItemIssueActions_txtActionItem")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
   source: function (request, response) {
        //get client value
        var c = $("#ucAddActionItemIssueActions_ddlClientAssignTo").val();
         var params= '{"ClientID":' + c + '}';
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetLogins.asmx/GetLogins",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });},
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        var email = GetEmail(ui.item.value);
        email = email + ";";
        emails.push(email);
        $("#ucAddActionItemIssueActions_hdnEmails").val(emails.join(""));
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

The web method (.asmx file) is this (just as a test case):

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Collections
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace := "http://tempuri.org/quikfix.jakah.com/GetLogins")> _
Public Class GetLogins
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetLogins(ByVal ClientID As Integer) As String()
        Dim myList As New ArrayList
        myList.Add("jstevens")
        myList.Add("jdoe")
        myList.Add("smartin")

        Dim arr() As String = CType(myList.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")), String())
        Return arr
    End Function
End Class
```

When running my app in the developer tools of chrome it is throwing an internal 500 error.  When I click on it it says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid:
>   application/json; charset=UTF-8.   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

The parameters all match so Im not sure why this is throwing an error.  Do I need anything in my `web.config` file to explicitly give any reference to my .asmx file?  This is an old 1.1 .net web app so I'm not sure if any changes to the web.config file need to be made?

Comment: `var params= '{"ClientID":"' + c + '"}';` wraps `c` in quotation marks as a string, but your code-behind method is expecting an `Integer`. Try `var params= '{"ClientID":' + c + '}';` instead (no quotes around `c`).

Comment: I'm not an Ajax expert, but I am fairly sure 1.1 predates widespread adoption of JSON.  Maybe `application/json` isn't a request format it recognizes.

Comment: Do you still use 1.1 .NET version? Check this article: http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/

Comment: @AnnL. You are probably right what format / contenttype do I need to change it to?  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @oJM86o  Good question, and I'm not sure, because I didn't do Ajax before .NET 2.0. The default delivery for a 1.1 web service (IIRC) is xml, so I would think "application/xml; charset=utf-8".  But if you plan to JSONify your results before returning them from the web service, using a 3rd party library, then it would probably be "application/text; charset=utf-8" since you'd be returning a string.

Comment: @oJM86o  Also the article that Mr. Rozhovetskiy linked to has a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 1.1 for the web service as well as the app, that web service won't know how to interpret JSON.  There are a lot of situations that produce the error you're getting, but I notice that the error you're getting is happening in a method called `ReadParameters`.  So I'm focusing on the parameters:

```
var params= '{"ClientID":' + c + '}';
```

I looked right past this the first time.  I'm not a 1.1 web service expert, nor an AJAX expert, but unless I much mistake, to the 1.1 web service that JSON would just be a string.  The web service has no ability to interpret (or return) JSON.

So I would try passing your single parameter just as an int:

```
var params = c;
```

And see what difference that makes.